# Is there a way to check if your Google Search Console account has index now API submissions?

Tags: google-index, google-api

Is there a console panel that I can see the GSC index now API submissions? I need to make sure a contractor that I'm arguing with isn't making API requests claiming stuff with errors is fixed.